# How do you assign an exception to a local variable in Python 2.5?

Tags: python, python-2.5

In Python 2.6+, you can handle exceptions like this:

```
  try:
    # stuff
  except Exception as e:
    return 'exception %s' % type(e)
```

What is the equivalent in 2.5?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like this :

```
try:
    # stuff
except Exception, e:
  return 'exception %s' % type(e)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to call `str()`, because you are already doing the interpolation using `%s`, `'exception %s' % type(e)` will work just fine

Comment: Edited my question as well. :)